# open a sourced terminal from python

Tags: python, terminal, operating-system

I'm trying to run a script which opens a new terminal for the user which is sourced from a different file.

My code looks like this at the moment:

```
os.system("gnome-terminal 'bash -e -c \"source " + path_to_file + "\"'")
```

Yes it does open a console which also stays open but what I want is also that the console is sourced to the specific file.

I also did a test with running a command with the sourced information dirctly in the above line and it worked. But if I try to start it and do the same it dosn't work.

I hope someone can tell me how I can make it that the terminal will open to the user and that it is sourced.

Comment: Have had any success without using `path_to_file` and hard coding in the source?

Comment: I just tested it but that didn't help either. Also at the end it has to be a variable because the user could select which one he wants.